# Create multiple jekyll pages from yaml without using a plugin

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am working on a Jekyll site on and I want to be able to have a page for each person in the group. I know I can use a collections to generate pages, if the files in the collection are markdown. I want to be able to have yaml files in the collection, then generate pages after passing each yaml file to a template.

People files might look like this:

```
# person-1.yaml
name: thingy m. bob
position: coffee fetcher
bio: no bio needed

# person-2.yaml
name: mars e. pan
position: head honcho
bio: expert in everything
```

Then a template file like this (people-template.md):

```
# {{ page.name }} - {{ page.position }}
{{ page.bio }}
```

And the output would be individual file under `/people/`, i.e, `/people/person-1`, `/people/person-2`, which are formatted as in the template, but using the `.yaml` files.

I am using GitHub pages, so I don't want to have to use any plugins which that doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something similar ... this is the setup I created:

```
- _Layouts
  - person.html
...
people
  - index.md (list of people - see code below)
  - _posts
    - 2015-01-01-person-one.md (ordering defined by date which is thrown away)
    - 2015-01-02-person-two.md
    - 2015-01-03-person-three.md
    ...
```

Then for a list of people you can use something like:

```
<ul>
{% for person in site.categories.people %}
    <li><a href="{{ person.url }}>{{ person.name}}"></a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

with each person being in the form

```
---
name: "thingy m. bob"
# using quotes to avoid issues with non-alpha characters
position: "coffee fetcher"
bio: "no bio needed"

layout: person
---

any markdown if you want more of a description
```

I hope that has given you something to start with ... I think that putting the `_posts` folder under the `people` folder will automatically set the category to `people`. If I am wrong, just add `category: people` to the yaml.

You can set the pattern for the post urls in _config.yaml if you want to remove the date part.

Good luck

Comment: Hmmm ... you might also be able to solve this using http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/ ... not used those before.